# Polymer simple element is not rendering

Tags: html, polymer, element

I'm trying to render a simple Polymer-element. I have followed the docs and it is not rendered. The weird thing is that a more complex polymer tags do work (such as `<dom-module id=""`> ), but no luck with `<polymer-element>`.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/daniel-element.html">
    <title>Polymer Learning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <daniel-element></daniel-element>
</body>
</html>
```

daniel-element.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="fav-color">
  <template>
    This is <b>{{owner}}</b>'s fav-color element.
    {{owner}} likes the color
    <span style="color: {{color}}">{{color}}</span>.
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      owner: "Daniel",
      color: "red"
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

When I run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

OR

```
polyserve
```

The browser does not render the element.
I have looked on this subject and did not found a solution.. thanks before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<polymer-element>` tag was used in older versions of Polymer. With 1.0 you need to use `<dom-module id="">` which does work as you have noticed. Have a look at the [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#local-dom-template) to find out more on specifying local DOM in 1.0.